# Oracle SQL - Grouping by CASE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query:

```
Select Player_Id,
Pt_Credit As Total_Points
From Player 
Where Trunc(Create_Dtime) = Trunc(Sysdate) - 90
And Trunc(Init_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-sep-1','yyyy-mon-dd')
Order by Total_Points Desc
```

Which gives me this result:

```
Player_ID      TOTAL_POINTS
  23452         1500
  23494         1000
  30934         500
```

and so on. I want to group these player_ids results into groups like 0-300 points, 301-600 points, 601-900 points , and greater than 900 points...so it would look like this in the results:

```
Point_Level     Count(Player_ID)
0-300            532
301-600          444
601-900          669
>900             185
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CASE ... WHEN`

```
SELECT players.clasification, count(players.player_id)
FROM (
    SELECT ROWNUM player_id, 
        (ROWNUM + 100) points,
        CASE
            WHEN (ROWNUM + 100) BETWEEN 0 AND 300 THEN
                '0-300'
            WHEN (ROWNUM + 100) BETWEEN 301 AND 600 THEN
                '301-600'
            WHEN (ROWNUM + 100) BETWEEN 601 AND 900 THEN
                '601-900'
            ELSE
                '> 900'
            END clasification
    FROM dual 
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000
) players 
GROUP BY players.clasification;
```

Or in your example:

```
SELECT 
    count(player.player_id),
    player.clasification
FROM (
    SELECT pl.*,
        CASE
            WHEN total_points BETWEEN 0 AND 300
                THEN '0-300'
            WHEN total_points BETWEEN 301 AND 600
                THEN '301-600'
            WHEN total_points BETWEEN 601 AND 900
                THEN '601-900'
            ELSE '> 900'
        END clasification
    FROM player pl
    WHERE 
            TRUNC(Create_Dtime)  = TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 90
        AND TRUNC(Init_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-sep-1', 'yyyy-mon-dd')

)
    Player
GROUP BY player.clasification;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select case 
    when Pt_Credit between 0 and 300 then '0 to 300'
    when Pt_Credit between 301 and 600 then '301 to 600'
    when Pt_Credit between 601 and 900 then '601 to 900'
    else '> 900'
end Total_Points
, count(*)
From Player 
Where Trunc(Create_Dtime) = Trunc(Sysdate) - 90
And Trunc(Init_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-sep-1','yyyy-mon-dd')
Group by case 
    when Pt_Credit between 0 and 300 then 0 
    when Pt_Credit between 301 and 600 then 1 
    when Pt_Credit between 601 and 900 then 2
    else 3
end
Order by Total_Points Desc
```

or

```
Select case 
    when Pt_Credit between 0 and 300 then '0 to 300'
    when Pt_Credit between 301 and 600 then '301 to 600'
    when Pt_Credit between 601 and 900 then '601 to 900'
    else '> 900'
end Total_Points
, count(*)
From Player 
Where Trunc(Create_Dtime) = Trunc(Sysdate) - 90
And Trunc(Init_Dtime) >= To_Date('2012-sep-1','yyyy-mon-dd')
Group by cast(Pt_Credit/300 as integer)
Order by Total_Points Desc
```